# Mongoskin MongoClient.connect sync

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

In the module mongoskin when getting the database object mongoskin does this in a sync fashion, hence the code:

```
var db = mongoskin.db(url, {
    native_parser: true
});
var myCollection = db.collection('myCollection');
```

I am curious, how do they achieve this? I've been looking at the mongoskin code I however do not fully understand it.

And here, you can see mongoskin simplifys it :

https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin#dbcollection-callback origin vs. mongoskin

Anyone know how mongoskin turned async code into sync fashion?

Comment: It's actually not synchronous at all if you look at the code, and the same basic thing is used in many higher level async adaptations. The "lie" here is that the `db` returned in that first line of code acutally does not connect to the database at all at that time. Only when the other later calls are made that actually require a connection is there any connection made. If you inspected the collection object ( just a console log and no other operations ) then you would see details that would support the database not actually being connected at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They say it in the beginning of the [readme](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin#origin-api-part):

> We make some common use functions in promise mode, we call it SkinClass of a normal Class. And the API is almost same with official API.

`db.collection('myCollection');` returns `SkinCollection` - a wrapper for native `Collection`, which will use `Collection` when it is available.

The magic lives here: https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/blob/master/lib/utils.js